How to use custom icons in Flutter
A very exciting question. How to add an ICON, just an icon, and not a picture, to the application. What I mean is that I have a class in which I specify the Icon. When adding this class, some icons are in the flutter, and some are not. How can I add them?
code
There is no such icon in the flutter
Icon pictures
I tried to connect different libraries in pub.dev (I would like without third-party applications) and also changed icon to images

Try to follow one of these articles: https://medium.com/deviniti-technology-driven-blog/the-best-way-to-add-custom-icons-to-your-flutter-project-6381ab697813, https://padymies.medium.com/flutter-custom-icons-c531b7e71bfd, https://dev.to/techwithsam/how-to-add-your-own-custom-icons-in-your-flutter-application-made-easy-1bnj

I'm going to the competition. And all I can use is VS CODE, Flutter Doc and Figma. Therefore, I cant access third-party sites. Is there any other way? Thanks for your comments

The https://www.fluttericon.com/ website appears to be open source https://github.com/ilikerobots/polyicon. Maybe you can run the website locally? They also have a pub package https://pub.dev/packages/fluttericon, which contains many icons to choose from.

You can use the service of the website Flutter icons : https://www.fluttericon.com/
Just create your icon font, download the package and use it in your code!

you could use imageIcon: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ImageIcon-class.html
it takes an icon that comes from an ImageProvider, e.g. an AssetImage.
